# accessing `this` inside async functions in methods of vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue.js class method that needs to call on an async function using `await`:

```
methods: {
   playRecording(path) {
      return await this.getAudioUrl(path)
   }
}
```

This results in the following error:

> Unexpected reserved word 'await'.

In order to fix this error, I re-wrote the code using `async` as such:

```
methods: {
    playRecording : async() => {
       console.log(this) // `this` evaluates to `undefined`
       var path = '/recordings/' + this.book
       return await this.getAudioUrl(path)
    }
}
```

While this does address the `await` error above, it results in a new error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'book')

`this` evaluates to `undefined`

How can I regain access to `this` inside a class method marked with `async`?

Comment: `methods: {
   async playRecording(path) {...`

Answer (score 2):

The calling method has to be defined as such:

```
async playRecording () {
```

This is incorrect:

```
playRecording : async() => {
```